# UISearchController & UISearchBar Subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

Aloha.

I am having trouble getting a custom subclass of UISearchController, VLSearchController, with a custom UISearch Bar to call any of its delegate methods in my UIViewController. My custom subclasses don't have any delegate methods of their own, but I thought that since they were subclasses... their delegate methods would be subclassed as well and need to be defined inside of the UIViewController that initializes the UISearchController.

After initializing the UISearchController, I set its delegate and the searchbar's delegate to the UIViewController:

```
_searchController = [[VLSearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; 
self.searchController.delegate = self;
```

The following delegate methods in my UIViewController don't get called:

```
#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;

#pragma mark - UISearchController
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController;

#pragma mark - UISearchResultsUpdating
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController;
```

Let me also mention that the reason that I subclassed the UISearchController as well as the UISearchBar was to get rid of the cancel button.
Do I need to add delegate methods to the subclasses? If so, would anybody mind explaining what these delegate methods would do?

EDIT: Addition of Code

UIViewController:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //// Search & Results Stuff
    _searchController = [[VLSearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x411229);

    [self.sfView addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];

    self.searchController.delegate  = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
} 

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (self.searchControllerWasActive) {
        self.searchController.active = self.searchControllerWasActive;
        _searchControllerWasActive = NO;

        if (self.searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder) {
            [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
            _searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder = NO;
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchController
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController 
{
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false; // stop from animating
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false;
}

- (void)didDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
    filteredPics=_pics;
}

#pragma mark - UISearchResultsUpdating

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {};
```

VLSearchController

```
@interface VLSearchController () 
@end

@implementation VLSearchController{
    UISearchBar *_searchBar;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{

    if (_searchBar == nil) {
        _searchBar = [[VLSearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    }
    return _searchBar;
}

   -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText 
{
        if ([searchBar.text length] > 0) {
            self.active = true;
        } else {
            self.active = false;
        }
    }
@end
```

VLSearchBar

```
@implementation VLSearchBar

-(void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton {
    // Do nothing...
}

-(void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // Do nothing....
}

@end
```

Comment: Does you class conform to `UISearchResultsUpdating` and `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol?

Comment: Yes, I have added the protocols <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating> to my UIViewController class.

Comment: Can you post the complete code (related to UISearchController)?

Comment: I have posted the UIViewController that uses the custom UISearchController (VLSearchController) as well as the VLSearchController and VLSearchBar code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the search bar's delegate to be your instance of VLSearchController. However that class does not conform to the UISearchBarDelegate protocol. I believe you want to set `_searchBar.delegate =  _searchBar` where you have implemented your delegate methods.

There can only be one delegate for the searchBar so decide which class you want to handle text changes and showing/hiding the cancel button and set the delegate accordingly. You also set the searchBar delegate to be the UIViewController in your viewDidLoad method.

In general, check to make sure you are setting all your delegates properly to ensure that their methods get called.

I believe you will need your instance variable to be an instance of your search bar subclass as well.

Comment: Ok. So I got rid of setting the delegate of _searchBar to be the VLSearchController. I kept the delegate  assignment in the viewDidLoad of the UIViewController. I chose the delegate to be the UIViewController because I deal with data structures that are specific to that UIViewController. Unfortunately, it still does not work.

Comment: I am unsure of what your last statement means... When I instantiate my VLSearchController, an instance of VLSearchBar is instantiated... therefore, the instance variable (VLSearchController) searchController, has a VLSearchBar instance accessible via: **self.searchController.searchBar** which is a subclass of UISearchBar

Comment: is there any reason you are using a custom search bar class and custom searchcontroller if all the search bar delegate methods will be implemented in your UIViewController? if there is no other reason, you may want to try removing those classes as they don't seem to be doing anything but initializing a new search bar which is styled in your view controller anyway.

Comment: given that your accepted answer involves ensuring that the searchBar delegate is set correctly, i'm wondering if my response could be given a vote or an accepted answer. glad you got it working. cheers :-)

Comment: I'll accept your answer cause it led me to the correct solution :) thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own problem. The solution is to move the following delegate method:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

into VLSearchController and setting `_searchBar.delegate=self` inside of VLSearchController's `-(UISearchBar *)searchBar`.

Answer (score -1):

Call the delegates to connect a delegate to the search bar. Like so

```
 @property(nonatomic, assign) id< UISearchControllerDelegate >     _searchController;


  _searchController = [[VLSearchController alloc]             
initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; 
self.searchController.delegate = self;


#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {}

 #pragma mark - UISearchController
 - (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController;

 #pragma mark - UISearchResultsUpdating
 - (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController   
 *)searchController;
```

Hope that this helps you if not sorry but this should work Have A Nice Day! =)

Comment: I have the search bar added programmatically. So connecting a non-existent search bar in the xib file to its delegate in IB won't help. In the code I posted, I set the delegates programmatically. thanks for the try though :)

Comment: hey could you upvote me though I need to get some more rep? ill research the prob some more you may have to add in the IB and make a ib property for it instead

Comment: You can still edit the properties of the search bar just give it a class name as well to refer to so it knows what to take from

Comment: But UISearchController programmatically sets the cancel to show  once the search bar text field is activated thus I need the cancel methods I have overridden in the VLSearchController to make this not happen. making an IB for the bar won't help. If you find me a solution, I'll upvote :)

Comment: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchControllerDelegate_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchControllerDelegate/didPresentSearchController:) this may work

Comment: Just hold up a second K?

Comment: Do I put that in the UIViewController or... in my custom VLSearchController? The proposed solution  did not fix my problem.